# HTML dropdown menu pops up even after it should've already been hidden

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am building a website which has categories in a dropdown menu, when the "categories" section in navbar gets hovered they display with a transition and also fade away. The problem I found is that even after the 0.25s transition which I added in my CSS the menu is still present.

So for example, I hover the "categories" section, my dropdown comes up exactly like I wanted with a 0.25s transition, then I hover away from the dropdown and it fades away with the same transition. But even when it is already invisible, if I put my cursor back in the area that the dropdown spawned lets say within 1 to 2 seconds (the dropdown already faded away and is fully hidden) it pops up again. This behavior can be seen in the JS fiddle, the design is crappy just to keep as least HTML and CSS as possible just to ilustrate the issue

I played around with the transition times but can't figure out what is causing this behavior

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/samig12/Lbfkxr45/1/

video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/60DYu.jpg

HTML:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../style.css">
<script src="../../../script.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Cyber-Electronics</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../../../images/cyber.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="navbar">
                
              

                      <a href="../../../index.html">
                        <img src="../../../images/logo.svg" height="60" width="60" alt="cyber electronics logo" class="cyberLogo">
                    </a>    

                </div>

                <ul class="nav-ul">  
                    <li>
                        <a href="../../../index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropCategories">
                        <a href="../../categories.html">Categories</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <div class="dropdown-header">
                                <p>Select your desired category</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <a href="../../hardware/hardware.html">Hardware</a>
                                    <a href="../../../404/404.html">Software</a>
                                    <a href="../../../404/404.html">Smart Devices</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="column">
                                    <a href="../../../404/404.html">Smart Home</a>
                                    <a href="../../../404/404.html">Photo Audio Video</a>
                                    <a href="../../../404/404.html">TV's</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="column">
                                    <a href="../../../404/404.html">Home Electronics</a>
                                    <a href="../../../404/404.html">Print & Office</a>
                                    <a href="../../../404/404.html">Gaming Zone</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../../../404/404.html">Report</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../../../404/404.html">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <a href="../../../404/404.html" target="_blank" class="nav-login-register">
                    Login / Register
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!----------------------------------------------  Product  ------------------------------------------------------------------->

       
        
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="footerContainer">
                <div class="footerContent">
                    <div class="footerLogo">
                        <img src="../../../images/inkscapecyber.png" alt="logo" height="45" width="140">
                    </div>
                    <p class="copyright">Cyber Electronics LLC. All Rights Reserved. 2021</p>
                    <div class="footerSocials">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com">
                            <img class="icons" src="../../../images/ig.png" alt="instagram" height="24" width="24">
                        </a>
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitter.com">
                            <img class="icons" src="../../../images/tw.png" alt="twitter" height="24" width="24">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </header>
    
    
    
    <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    .dropCategories
{
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropCategories:hover .dropdown-content
{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility 0.25s, opacity 0.25s linear;
}
.dropdown-content 
{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0.15s, opacity 0.15s linear;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-header 
{
    background: rgb(42, 48, 71);
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.column 
{
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%; /* change to 33.33% if 3 more sub-categories should be added*/
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(42, 48, 71);
    height: 400px;
}

.column a 
{
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s linear;
    transition: 0.8s linear; 
    float: none;
    color: rgb(226, 223, 238);
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover 
{
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s linear;
    transition: 0.8s linear; 
    background-color: rgb(30, 34, 51);
    color: #f75c6f;
}

.row:after 
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.nav-ul
{
    height: 8rem;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li
{
    padding: 0 3rem;
    line-height: 8rem;
    transition: background-color;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li:hover
{
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear;
    transition: 0.5s linear; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    color: #f75c6f;
}

.nav-right ul li
{
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}

.nav-right ul li:nth-child(1)
{
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}

.nav-right ul li:last-child
{
    border-right: none;
}

.nav-right i
{
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.nav-right i:first-child
{
    margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-logo 
{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 8px 8px 35px;
}

.nav-login-register
{
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 22px 35px 8px 8px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(43, 54, 77);
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s linear;
    transition: 0.8s linear; 
}

.nav-login-register:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s linear;
    transition: 0.8s linear; 
    background: #26d982;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #26d982;
}

.navbar
{
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.animation-div
{
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of using opacity & visibility contents are invisible on html.that's why hover problem accrue.

```css
.dropCategories
{
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropCategories:hover .dropdown-content /*this is the class that is causing me trouble*/
{
     height:100%;
    transition: height 0.25s;
}
.dropdown-content 
{
    /* visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0; */
    height:0px;
    transition: height 0.15s;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-header 
{
    background: rgb(42, 48, 71);
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.column 
{
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%; /* change to 33.33% if 3 more sub-categories should be added*/
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(42, 48, 71);
    
}

.column a 
{
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s linear;
    transition: 0.8s linear; 
    float: none;
    color: rgb(226, 223, 238);
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover 
{
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s linear;
    transition: 0.8s linear; 
    background-color: rgb(30, 34, 51);
    color: #f75c6f;
}

.row:after 
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.nav-ul
{
    height: 8rem;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li
{
    padding: 0 3rem;
    line-height: 8rem;
    transition: background-color;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li:hover
{
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear;
    transition: 0.5s linear; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    color: #f75c6f;
}

.nav-right ul li
{
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}

.nav-right ul li:nth-child(1)
{
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}

.nav-right ul li:last-child
{
    border-right: none;
}

.nav-right i
{
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.nav-right i:first-child
{
    margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-logo 
{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 8px 8px 35px;
}

.nav-login-register
{
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 22px 35px 8px 8px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(43, 54, 77);
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s linear;
    transition: 0.8s linear; 
}

.nav-login-register:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s linear;
    transition: 0.8s linear;
    background: #26d982;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #26d982;
}

.navbar
{
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.animation-div
{
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../style.css">
    <script src="../../../script.js"></script>
    <head>
        <title>Cyber-Electronics</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../../../images/cyber.png">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="navbar">
                    
                  

                          <a href="../../../index.html">
                            <img src="../../../images/logo.svg" height="60" width="60" alt="cyber electronics logo" class="cyberLogo">
                        </a>    

                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav-ul">  
                        <li>
                            <a href="../../../index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropCategories">
                            <a href="../../categories.html">Categories</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <div class="dropdown-header">
                                    <p>Select your desired category</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <a href="../../hardware/hardware.html">Hardware</a>
                                        <a href="../../../404/404.html">Software</a>
                                        <a href="../../../404/404.html">Smart Devices</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <a href="../../../404/404.html">Smart Home</a>
                                        <a href="../../../404/404.html">Photo Audio Video</a>
                                        <a href="../../../404/404.html">TV's</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <a href="../../../404/404.html">Home Electronics</a>
                                        <a href="../../../404/404.html">Print & Office</a>
                                        <a href="../../../404/404.html">Gaming Zone</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="../../../404/404.html">Report</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="../../../404/404.html">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <a href="../../../404/404.html" target="_blank" class="nav-login-register">
                        Login / Register
                    </a>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!----------------------------------------------  Product  ------------------------------------------------------------------->

           
            
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="footerContainer">
                    <div class="footerContent">
                        <div class="footerLogo">
                            <img src="../../../images/inkscapecyber.png" alt="logo" height="45" width="140">
                        </div>
                        <p class="copyright">Cyber Electronics LLC. All Rights Reserved. 2021</p>
                        <div class="footerSocials">
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com">
                                <img class="icons" src="../../../images/ig.png" alt="instagram" height="24" width="24">
                            </a>
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitter.com">
                                <img class="icons" src="../../../images/tw.png" alt="twitter" height="24" width="24">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>

        </header>
        
        
        
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you after playing around with the height on `dropCategories:hover` so that it only has the same height as the dropdown menu, it works perfect thank you for the help